# Парсинг docx файлов с помощью python

Tags: python, парсер, docx

Есть docx файл следующего содержания:

```
Параметр 1: 2,3,4

Параметр 2: 10,11,12

Параметр 3: 8,9,10
```

Я хочу его прочитать и вывести все, что идёт после "Параметр 2:" с помощью python

Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?

Comment: Ну, вы же здесь не первый день. Вы считаете, что вам должны здесь это решить? и предоставить готовый код? Добавьте ваши попытки решения, ошибки, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться...

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document


doc = Document('your_path_to_doc.docx')
pars = doc.paragraphs
    
df = pd.DataFrame([i.text.split(': ') for i in pars], columns=['params', 'numbers'])
df['numbers'] = df['numbers'].apply(lambda x: list(eval(x))) # эту строчку можно не использовать в принципе, тогда формат вывода будет как строка, а не как список
print(df[df.params.str.contains('Параметр 2')].numbers.values[0])
```